# Tensorflow Keras GCP ML engine model serving

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm working on an image classifier with **tensorflow estimator** + **keras** retraining the last layer of a pretrained application **inception_v3** on **GCP ML engine**.

The keras model is exported with `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator` and the input function receive the path of the image stored on **GCP cloud storage** open the image with `tf.image.decode_jpeg` and return a dataset with the following format `dict(zip(['inception_v3_input'], [image])), label`

I'm trying to define the `tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver` but I'm having some trouble defining it.

The model is serving correctly the prediction with the `predict` method using the input function without the labels.
My idea was to reuse the input_function to decode the image passing only the path of the image on cloud storage to the prediction also for the google endpoint, but I can't understand how to do it.

Thank's for your help

Comment: Might this help? https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#decoding_image_data_and_resizing_it

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, your question is how to get the file from Cloud Storage, considering that you want to decode the image this way:

```
image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)
```

So, in this case, you can use:

```
image_string = file_io.FileIO(filename, mode='r')
```

By importing file_io first:

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
```

According to [the comments on this question about reading input data from GCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783189/reading-input-data-from-gcs/39784556), using the file_read function should provide the same results since " there was a bunch of work done to abstract file io and file systems, so there all the io functionality works consistently". So you can try also with read_file function.